# SpecFlow Bindings stay partially white after Update

Tags: visual-studio, binding, visual-studio-2017, specflow

I updated SpecFlow to Specflow 3 recently and after restarting Visual Studio some of my bindings turned white, while others seemed to work as they did before and stayed colorful.
I already deleted the cache file fpr specflow in the %temp% directory and the bindings seemed to work.
But after starting the build they turned white again.
Any idea how to solve this? Any other issues I found only covered problems where all bindings turned white.

Comment: Did you read their [Upgrading to SpecFlow 3](https://specflow.org/blog/updating-to-specflow-3/) guide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating from SpecFlow 2.x to 3.x is not straight forward. There were breaking changes that require existing test projects to get reconfigured.

**First, make sure you have updated the SpecFlow Plugin for Visual Studio (not the NuGet package for your project, the *plugin for Visual Studio* available via Tools --> Extensions).**

Then go through the following steps to upgrade your configuration:

1. Open the Visual Studio options: Tools --> Options
2. Choose "SpecFlow" in the options sidebar
3. Make sure **Enable SpecFlowSingleFileGenerator CustomTool** is set to **False**

   [image: Screenshot of SpecFlow options panel in Visual Studio]

   Click "OK" if you made changes.
4. Right-click on your feature files, and choose "Properties".
5. Make sure the **CustomTool** property is empty. If it is not empty, delete the value.
6. Repeat steps 4 and 5 for each feature file, then click the "Save All" button in the Visual Studio toolbar (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>).

You can select multiple .feature files in Solution Explorer, right-click on the selection and do steps 4-5 in bulk to speed things up.

Further reading: [Upgrading from SpecFlow 2.x to 3.x](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Guides/UpgradeSpecFlow2To3.html).