# Specflow getting started tutorial gives error featurefile.cs not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio, specflow

I inherited a solution with Specflow in it, which is not working.
To brush up on my Specflow I started with their tutorial which, can be found here:[Specflow Tutorial](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/getting-started/en/latest/GettingStarted/Step1.html)
All went well till the build attempt in [step 4](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/getting-started/en/latest/GettingStarted/Step4.html). I don't get the clean build as promised but this:
Error CS2001: Source file 'C:\Users\sighk00\source\SpecflowCalculator\SpecFlowCalulator.Specs\Features\Calculator.feature.cs' could not be found.
Which in it self is a truth big as day, is is not there.
So what is not in the tutorial to get one?

Solution sofar[image]

Specflow Settings:
[image: Settings]

Error message:
[image: Error]

Comment: https://docs.specflow.org/projects/getting-started/en/latest/GettingStarted/Step3.html

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya that step went ok. what is your point?

Comment: I think if you follow this step, it should create a new project under the solution along with folders such as Features, Drivers, Hooks, Steps with respective files underneath.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya it did add the project and feature file. It dit not generate a .cs file for the feature file during the build, which is the source of the error.
There used to be a custom tool to generate these .cs files. But I see no mention of it any more

Comment: There is no custom tool anymore. Check Tools > SpecFlow > General in Visual Studio. Make sure the legacy setting called something like CustomToolGenerator is set to `False`. I don't remember the exact phrasing of the setting.

Comment: I don't think this is an exact duplicate, but it might be the same fix: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65810678/3092298

Comment: @GregBurghardt Thanks for the tip. I have added my settings and the error message.
The settings seem to be in order, and I do have syntax highlighting it seems...

Comment: @k.c. could you post the project somewhere, that I can have a look at it?

Comment: @AndreasWillich no that is no longer possible , the dev VM has been recycled. 
A removal of the pluigin, and visual studio  did not help. So we  started from scratch on new VM.

Answer (score 0):

- Close Visual Studio
- Navigate to specflow nuget packages (in my case %userprofile%\nuget\packages
- Delete specflow related packages
- Restart Visual Studio and build sln

Had the same issue and the above fixed it for me.
Deleting the bin/debug folder may also resolve this issue.